# Xamarin.Android - Why do my horizontal drawable buttons have no space between them?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

My buttons end up looking like this:
[image: like this]

That's 4 toggle buttons (well, 3 and a half), the 2nd is selected. I'm setting padding in the drawable, but for some reason the padding is either being ignored, or being used on the button border to the text. If I don't use a drawable, the default Android buttons look fine, with no space between them.

Sample of my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ToggleButton
        android:text="@string/btn_resp_tmp"
        android:id="@+id/resp1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/CustomSelector"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <ToggleButton
    (...)
```

Sample of my drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape >
        <solid
            android:color="#FF9800" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#E0E0E0" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item >
    <shape >
        <solid
            android:color="#E0E0E0" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#E0E0E0" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"  />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as my google-fu is seriously failing me on this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the shape padding as following code:

```
<padding
      android:left="10dp"
      android:right="10dp"
      android:top="10dp"
      android:bottom="10dp" />
```

That means the red line is 10dp.

[image]

But the in selector you can not defined the shape margin. So as a workaroud you can set your toggle button margin :

```
<ToggleButton
        ......
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         ..... />
```

Comment: You are a timesaver thank you. Using margins in the layout had occurred me, but I thought there must be something I was doing wrong, since default Android buttons have margins "built in". It's freeing not looking for an answer anymore.